# Three.js Resizing Canvas

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have been working on a 3D project where we show 3D object in the web browser using Three.js Library.

The problem is:

- 1st the model is displayed in a small `dom` element or when the browser window itself is small.
- Then when the window (or the `dom` element is resized) the model become pixelated

Following are some screenshots:

#### Before resize:

[image]

#### After resize:

[image]

#### How it should be after resize:

### [image]

Here is the part of code that is setting the the model dimensions (height and width), and this function gets called when the resize event if fired:

```js
console.log("domChanged fired")

instance.domBoundingBox = instance.dom.getBoundingClientRect();
instance.domCenterPos.x = instance.domBoundingBox.width / 2 + instance.domBoundingBox.left;
instance.domCenterPos.y = instance.domBoundingBox.height / 2 + instance.domBoundingBox.top;

var width = instance.dom.clientWidth, height = instance.dom.clientHeight;
instance.domWidthHalf = width / 2, instance.domHeightHalf = height / 2;

// TODO: fire event to expose it to site developers

// here we should update several values regarding width,height,position
if(instance.cameraReal) {
    instance.cameraReal.aspect = instance.dom.clientWidth / instance.dom.clientHeight;
    instance.cameraReal.updateProjectionMatrix();
}

if(instance.renderer3D)
    instance.renderer3D.setSize(instance.dom.clientWidth, instance.dom.clientHeight);
```

Can anybody give me a hint? I've been working on that a couple of days already but no clue so far

Comment: AFAIK `setSize` changes the canvas `width`/`height` (render resolution) for you and uses the new size for `glViewport`. Can you double check `instance.dom.clientWidth/Height` are actually changing? It looks like the canvas is changing size and not its internal resolution.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Finally the problem were solved the actually problem was coming from because the application is using the `THREE.EffectComposer` object, in the class constructor a composer object were created like following:

```
this.composer = new THREE.EffectComposer(this.renderer3D);
```

So as for the renderer, the composer needed to have the size updated after the event handler function like following:

```
if(instance.renderer3D)
    instance.renderer3D.setSize(instance.dom.clientWidth, instance.dom.clientHeight);
if(instance.composer)
    instance.composer.setSize(instance.dom.clientWidth, instance.dom.clientHeight);
```

And this fixed the issue perfectly :)

Answer (score 158):

So the canvas element can be resized like every other element. What you want to do is tell the render and camera to resize the contents of your canvas as well.

```
window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

function onWindowResize(){

    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

}
```

Comment: its alreay done, you can see it in the code snipet I've shared in the code

Comment: Just wanted to separate the answer from the question for anybody else that might have this problem. Cool building btw.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the help :), actually the problem is solved by now, I'll try to find a time to write an answer

Comment: Beginners don't get tripped up by use of window here, you may be using your own container for your renderer, substitute that container for window

Comment: super old thread, but this helped me. `updateProjectionMatrix` is what I was missing. Thanks

Answer (score 14):

I applied Shawn Whinnery's answer to my needs with React JS:

Start listener onMount:

```
componentDidMount() {
  window.addEventListener('resize', this.handleResize, false)
}
```

Remove listener onUnmount (because we like garbage collection):

```
componentWillUnmount() {
  window.removeEventListener('resize', this.handleResize, false)
}
```

Install handler function:

```
handleResize = () => {
  this.camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight
  this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix()
  this.renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight)
}
```

Fat arrow syntax is used to avoid binding `this`. The code will not work if you have this: `handleResize() { ... }`, but of course, it would work if you added this to your constructor:

```
this.handleResize = this.handleResize.bind(this)
```

**Final note:** confirm that your camera is `this.camera` and your renderer is `this.renderer`. Besides that, you should be able to paste it all in.

Answer (score 4):

For those googling, if you want to start off quick with a helper util that does the resizing for you, check out this github: https://github.com/jeromeetienne/threex.windowresize

The only thing you have to do is install it via `bower` and initialise it:

```
new THREEx.WindowResize(renderer, camera)
```

Comment: This method is the easiest. Just include the js file and initialize the resizer. Works perfectly.

Comment: Reading my own comment after 7 years. Please don't use this anymore 

Comment: @polyclick can you explain why we should not use this anymore? please update your answer.

Comment: @doo_dah library is soooo old, last commit is 10 years ago, I wouldn't trust it anymore. Time to move on. Also, resizing is super simple anyway. I don't see why I used a library for that 

Answer (score -5):

try antialias property to resolve pixelation problem by 50 - 70%

e.g :`var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias:true});`

Comment: The "pixelation" here is due to subsampling since the renderer was not upscaled to the new window size, not due to aliasing.